# Ionic / angular form validation for pick file

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic/angular application. My requirement is to pickup files from the device file manager and upload to server after submitting. I did this using the pick file functionality in ionic cordova.

But I'm getting a problem in adding validators to this pickfile. Even without adding files and clicking submit its taking. I want to add required field for this as I added for the subject line.

Below is my code.

HTML file:

```
<form  [formGroup]="sendDocsForm">
<ion-item>
<ion-label>Subject: </ion-label>
 <ion-input type="text" formControlName="subject" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>
 <div class="error-messages">
    <ion-label
      *ngIf="sendDocsForm.get('subject').hasError('required') && (signupMobile.get('subject').dirty || signupMobile.get('subject').touched)"
      color="danger">
      Enter Subject line</ion-label>
  </div>

   <ion-item>
   <div (click)="pickFile()">
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      <p style="margin:0px;">Add Files</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-addfiles">
    <div *ngFor="let item of docPaths; let i=index">
      <p (click)="editDocRules(item)">{{ item.name }} </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Submit

.TS file:

```
this.sendDocsForm = this.fb.group({
  subject: new FormControl ('', Validators.compose([ Validators.required])),
});


  pickFile() {
    const filter = { mime: 'application/pdf' };
   this.fileChooser.open().then(fileuri => {
  this.filePath.resolveNativePath(fileuri).then(resolvednativepath => {
    console.log(resolvednativepath);
    this.returnPath = resolvednativepath;
    this.fileName = resolvednativepath.substring(
      resolvednativepath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1
    );
    this.fileType = this.fileName.substring(
      this.fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1
    );
    const docPath: ItemDoc = new ItemDoc(
      Date.now(),
      this.fileName,
      this.returnPath
    );
    this.docPaths.push(docPath);
  });
});
}
```

I want to make the {{item.name}} in the p Tag of the add file as a required field but I don't understand how to do this. Please let me know how I can do this.

Thank you.

Comment: can anyone help me on this please, i got struck in this from last 15 days

Comment: use `<ion-button [disabled]="yourDisabledBoolean">Submit Files</ion-button>` and keep it disabled till user Select a File.

Comment: can you add your `html` and `ts` file completely over here?

Comment: add a dynamic form control [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms)